# Pybind11: Cannot initialize object parameter of type 'const std::runtime_error' with an expression of type 'pybind11::error_already_set'

Tags: python, c++, binding, pybind11

I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <python3.8/Python.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("example_function", &add, "Bind example function");
 }
```

And CLion is showing me an error in the line with `PYBIND11_MODULE...`:
`Cannot initialize object parameter of type 'const std::runtime_error' with an expression of type 'pybind11::error_already_set'`

[Pybind11 documentation says](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/exceptions.html#handling-python-exceptions-cpp) that this exception came from python, but I didn't call any python functions or anything.

Comment: @Ibelkov please could you add some more details to reproduce? Was this a compile error, link error or from importing the module?
What command are you using to compile this example?